# Can you block and hit the ball over the net in volleyball?

Tags: rules, volleyball

So playing with friends the other day and this happened. Team A set the ball for their attacking player (3rd touch), he tried to dink the ball behind the blocker. It was a horrible touch and the blocker managed to block it.

Now here is the issue. As soon as the blocker made the block he noticed that it will drop in his own side. So before the ball went below the net line he managed to hit it again into the opposing team side. Is that allowed ?

In other words, he made two consecutive touches above the net: blocking and pushing the ball to the other side.